# Why does NSDateFormatter return nil?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Why is `lDateFormatted` `nil` on iPhone simulator 3.1.2 after executing this piece of code?

```
NSString *lDateString = @"Wed, 17 Feb 2010 16:02:01";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *lDateFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString: lDateString ];
```

Any ideas appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to be using `HH` for hours, that's 0-23 / military style
Also, you may need to put single ticks around your comma like `','`

Reference: [the UTS doc](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and [date formatting guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).

Comment: In this case the ticks didn't seem to be necessary, but I put them in anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The DateFormatter format is correct, but you've probably set the wrong locale. Try this one (working sample code of one of my projects):

> NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
>   NSLocale *enUS = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
>   [formatter setLocale:enUS];
>   [enUS release];
>   [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
>   ...
>   [formatter release]

Comment: Beware: if current device is set to military time (24 hr format), if you force the "en_US" locale in the NSDateFormatter, you may end up with a nil date object.