# NSDateFormatter is returning null date

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Below is my code

```
 NSString *dateandtime =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.eventtime];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateandtime];
```

if i print my self.event name i am getting the output as `Mon, 7 Jan 2013 15:30:00 CST` but when i pass this string in `NSDateFormatter` i am getting `null` value i don't know why i tried `many` `combinations` of `date formats`, but i cant solve it, can anyone help me

Comment: in your self.event, you are getting CST, it should be time zone for example +0530

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause but if it is showing 7 Jan then that should be "d MMM" not "dd MMM"

Comment: i am getting that from xml, how can i change it in to time zone

Comment: i tried Fogmeister, but it doesn't word

Comment: @Fogmeister : 7 Jan should be dd MMM not as d MMM. You cant make two formatters for 1-9 and 10-31.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : dd is the zero padded day (i.e. 01, 02, 03, ..., 29, 30, 31). d is the non-zero padded day (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ..., 29, 30, 31).

Comment: I think what you require is :

Why does NSDateFormatter return nil?[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254003/why-does-nsdateformatter-return-nil?rq=1

Comment: @AnoopVaidya  and @Fogmeister : it will work for both `d` and `dd`  in these situation

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838497/nsdateformatter-not-working-properly-with-utc

Comment: @PradeepKumar you got the solution?? otherwise see my bellow answer i use with your string like NSString *dateandtime = @"Mon, 7 Jan 2013 15:30:00 CST";
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [self convertStringToDate:dateandtime];
    NSLog(@"\n\n Date is %@",dateFromString); and it will give me th output Date is 2013-01-07 10:00:00 +0000 dude.. just use formater with [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'CST'"]; this

Comment: Why are you allocating an NSDate object and then throwing it away??

Comment: Why do you have the first line if self.eventtime is already a NSString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem as Per Prateek  comments, now its working for me...Thanks Prateek.

```
in your self.event, you are getting CST, it should be time zone for example +0530
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"];
```

Comment: I checked in my system, only then i posted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method for getting the `NSDate` from `NSString` date

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [self convertStringToDate:dateandtime];
```

Paste this below method in your `.m` file...

```
-(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *) date {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        NSDate *nowDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'CST'"];// set format here  format in which the date should be

        date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
        nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
        // NSLog(@"date============================>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : %@", nowDate);
        return nowDate;
}
```

For More Information About `NSDate` component see this post of My Blog [NSDate-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/date-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk.html)

Comment: @PradeepKumar you got it?? now i just update the answer , its return Date is 2013-01-07 10:00:00 +0000 output..

Comment: @PradeepKumar see my another answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251633/convert-string-to-nsdate-with-custom-format/13251656#13251656 like your question

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
- (NSString *)formattedDate:(NSString*)dateSte {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone];
    NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateSte];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE,MMM d,''yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    return strDate;
}
```